# Best way of implementing live search and pagination with big amount of data

Tags: jquery, json, django, pagination

I would like to implement a real time search of data that's paginated. I'm using Django for the pagination and jQuery for the live search. When implementing this I stumbled upon the following issue: live search works only in the first page. Of course! It only searchs within the displayed data. Well, then I thought, maybe I can have a JSON loaded on the client and live search from there displaying and hiding as I please. But! What if the JSON is too big for the client to handle. Also, how big would it need to be for the client to collapse?

I've been toying with the idea of using two different kind of searches. For example, displaying data between two dates and from that result live searching the JSON.

Am I complicating things too much?

Note: I can add the code I'm using if it's necessary, I just didn't want to make this too long.

Comment: Please provide more information, you're giving us very little information. Code would work.
And what you're refering to as Big Data is in fact not Big Data.
Please post (relevant parts) of your view and template/javascript so we can help you

Comment: You answered your own question:  You can't search data within the browser unless the data is loaded within the browser.  If you feel the that the data is too large to fit in the browser all at once, then implement your search on the server.

Comment: @little_birdie I was wondering how large would the Json have to be to have problems in the client.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out django-datatables or django ez-tables. They have pagination, ajax, searching and sorting built in.

Comment: I would like to be able to implement my own solution, but I will check them anyway. Thanks!